# Android native app has data my device browsers wants. How to get this data?

Tags: javascript, android, html, native

## Question :

How can I store data from my native app and then use that stored data inside my device's browser.
I do not think there is a way to pass data from a native app to a native browser application.

## What I can't do - security is important

- use the native webview
- pass query parameters in my URI : example : mywebapp.com?param1=cant

## First idea [from this website](http://www.howtodroid.com/2014/03/use-mobile-browser-local-files-android.html)

- write a file to the native device's storage
- use my device's browser to open this file and either read it (if possible, or screen scrape the data)
- once I have the data, map the data into something usable

## Answer :

*pending*

## What I found out so far...

I need to store user information without a HIPPA violation.
You can read in files via the browser but not HTTP(s) requests.
You can use Google Drive to store files as Chris has mentioned below. [google drive](http://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata)
Will this raise flags and cause Violations? Looking into that now.
So I found out you can pass headers to open your browser app and open a webpage (possibly). Another issue is ... we have applications logging each call to our server. These logging applications log *everything*, even the headers. So this idea is out as well.

### Benjamin Franklin

> An investment in knowledge pays the best interest.

### Thomas Edison

> I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.

Comment: Theres the possibility to call java functions from javascript, may search for it in the java webview class...

Comment: yes, I have a gist on this, but we cannot use a webview: (gitst)[https://gist.github.com/wesleyduff/403fc3a24f5a0f4508ef0e5f55a95ae9]

Comment: What about queries?

Comment: Does it have to be a local transfer? Because why not send the data to your server?

Comment: it is user data, we want to pass user data to browser so they do not have to write all their data again.

Comment: @Jonasw that is one of the things I cannot do. Due to security

Comment: @WesDuff Don't the users log in? You could use Google Drive though: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata

Comment: @ChrisG I will research this avenue and post back. Thanks